# apple llvm 9.0 can not use flag c++17

Tags: xcode, llvm, c++17, clang++

When I try some features of c++17, I build my code in command line as follow:

```
llvm-g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp
```

but it failed. I got:

```
error: invalid value 'c++17' in '-std=c++17'
```

the version of my llvm-g++ is:

```
[wjy@wjy-mba] cpp$ llvm-g++ -v
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

and at the same time, I can build my code in Xcode (with c++17).
[Xcode setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlZ7z.png)

Answer (score 5):

`-std=c++17` was added in Clang 5.0.0 (released very recently - earlier this month - see http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html).

This page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Latest_versions appears to believe Xcode 9.0 is still using the LLVM/Clang 4.0 release. This is in agreement with the error you're running into.

Comment: Wow thank you. May I ask one more question? What flags the Xcode used? When I select "std=c++17" in Xcode it will use "std=c++1z"? And why my code works well in Xcode and get compile error in command line with "c++1z"? (my code is just: auto [a, b, c] = sometuples;)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "what flags the Xcode used." But as far as why `c++1z` works: `c++1z` was used in place for `c++17` before C++17 was finalized. Compilers were implementing some feature that were already confirmed for 17, but since the final "standard" wasn't released yet, `c++17` wasn't set in stone yet. Most C++17 features are available with `c++1z` in recent versions of GCC (e.g. 7.X series) and Clang (e.g. 4.X series), because the developers were pretty on top of implementing the new confirmed features. Your code example works on my command line with `-std=c++1z`.

Comment: ^^ using `clang++ -std=c++1z`

Comment: Yes！You are right！ It worked！Thank you again！Maybe，I made some mistake the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the flag -std=c++1z

Comment: Thank you first. When I use flag -std=c++1z in command line, I got some compile error. But it works well in Xcode, it really makes me confused.

Answer (score 1):

Apple-LLVM 10 that comes with Xcode 10 supports C++17 and C++20 draft:

```
note: use 'c++98' or 'c++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++98' or 'gnu++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments and GNU
      extensions' standard
note: use 'c++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments and GNU extensions'
      standard
note: use 'c++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments and GNU extensions'
      standard
note: use 'c++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments and GNU extensions'
      standard
note: use 'c++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020' standard
note: use 'gnu++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020 with GNU extensions'
      standard
```